# Ordering the display items alphabetically in Django-Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am now able to display the item I want using the `list_display[]` but I would like them to displayed alphabetically. How do you make that the `list_display` is ordered alphabetically?

Example in Django-admin:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('upper_case_name',)

    def upper_case_name(self, obj):
      return ("%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)).upper()
    upper_case_name.short_description = 'Name'
```

How to alter this to display alphabetically? Need some help on this...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Set `ModelAdmin.ordering = ('foo', )` to order your admin.

**Example**

```
class TeamRoleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   """ Team Role admin view with modifications """
   model = TeamRole
   ordering = ('team', 'role', 'user')
   list_display = ['id', 'user', 'team', 'role']
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering

Modify global model meta class, override ModelAdmin.queryset, there are many ways but you most likely want the Admin ordering.

Comment: Thanks.. looked at it but wasn't sure how to use it... but your example clarifies the doubt...

Comment: one qn: where to place ModelAdmin.ordering = ('foo', )? it should be separate from the actual code? am i right?

Comment: lakesh: in your ModelAdmin definition, right beside stuff like list_display = ('foo', 'bar',). The syntax is similar for a reason!

Answer (score 4):

In your models `Meta` you can specify `ordering = ['first_name', 'last_name']`.